# How to use select_tag and submit_tag in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a dropdowns and button save using select_tag and submit_tag
How i can do that ?
and if i have function in controller call save how i can pass parameter from value of dropdown to the function?

What exacly do submit_tag ?

old version of ruby please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
# in you view file

<%= form_tag your_path do %>
  <%= select_tag "option_id", options_for_select([["Option 1", 1], ["Option 2", 2]]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

If you are selecting `Option 1`, then in controller you'll get value in `params[:option_id]`.

If you want to submit this form via `POST` request, then use like:

```
<%= form_tag your_path, method: :post do %>
  <%= select_tag "option_id", options_for_select([["Option 1", 1], ["Option 2", 2]]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: option_id ? in this code 1 or 2 ? or option 1 and option 2

Comment: And what mean your_path? whats is path should be ?

Comment: And in controller what can i do to check what value selected ?

Comment: In `params` you get value like 1 or 2 whatever you'll select. Here `your_path` means after submit in which path you want to get the submitted value.

Comment: path here should be function in controller ?

Comment: please another think : where i choose value and click in save after refresh dropdown not changed ! if value default equal to option1 i changed to option2 after click in send button she return to option1 why ?